# How to construct vector or list in testWithParam Parameter

Tags: c++, googletest

I am new to google test.
To test a class method, i have created a struct with the necessary variables

This is the sample model which i am working on.

```
    struct A {
    int a;
    int b;

    A(int _a, int _b) : a(_a), b(_b){}

    };

    struct B : public A {
     bool btest;

    B( A _aStruct, bool _b) : A(_Struct), btest(_b) {}

    };

    struct C : public B {

    std::vector<int> xVec;

    C(B _bStruct, std::vector<int>_xVec) : B(_bStruct) , xVec(_xVec){}
    };

    class Test : public classToTest , public testing::TestWithParam<C>
    {
     void SetUp()
    {
     //.....
    }

    };

    //Instantiate the test case with Parameters
    INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Sampletest , Test, Values (B(1, 2, true), std::vector<int>(10,12,11)));

TEST_P(Test, TestSample )
{
 ...

}
```

I am getting Error in the Vector Construction. 
How to get the vector or list Constrcuted in TestWithParam ???

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P is work without Vector for the Struct B.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please add the full error message to the question.

Comment: `B( A _aStruct, bool _b) : A(_Struct), btest(_b)` -> `B( A _aStruct, bool _b) : A(_aStruct), btest(_b)`? Is it a typo?

Comment: no instance of constructor matches the argumemt "std:: vector < _ty, _Alloc >  "  matches the argument list  Argument types are (int, int, int).                      
 Function definition for NSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P s not found

Comment: @BenshP Please provide [mcve], along with **copy-pasted** (not paraphrased) error message.

Comment: This is not a valid construction for `std::vector`. Is it a typo: `std::vector(10,12,11)` -> `std::vector<int>{10,12,11}`?

Comment: Error (active) E0289 no instance of constructor "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector [with _Ty=int, _Alloc=std::allocator<int>]" matches the argument list
Error C2440  '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<T>>'
        with
        [
            T=int
        ]
Error C2440  '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::vector<unsigned int,std::allocator<_Elem>>'
        with
        [
            _Elem=RWUChar32
        ]

Comment: Working after changing the braces .. Thank You YSC. Type in code .. my bad

Comment: @BenshP Please do not use comments to add information, instead [edit] the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

The vector initialization was Wrong. it has to be installed with std::vector{10,12,11}.

thanks @YSC